# Make an exe file run through a bat file without having to do it manually

Tags: batch-file

Thanks in advance, I'm trying to run an exe file through a bat file without having to do it manually (drag drop/ look up file every single time i try to open)

Comment: to do what manually ? start the bat ?!

Comment: to have the file run through the bat before starting without me having to manually do it

Comment: i dont get the point ?! So instead of starting the exe you start a bat ? - Thats still 1 Klick ?! (either bat or exe) or am i getting sth wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
start file_location.exe
```

As far as I can tell from the question, you'd need to look up the file location once and place it into the batch file using the start command

Comment: can you tell me how to do that? i'm a beginner, thanks in advance, also remember that i want the exe file to run through the bat file.. the bat file is not just opening the exe file

Comment: Ok, so first, you'll need to find the location of your executable. It might be on your desktop, it might be in program files but you need to know the location. Next, edit your batch file. In it, put the command `start`, a space, and then the location of your file in quotes, such as 'C:/program files/etc.exe'. Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, thanks. ill try it now and let you know if it works

Comment: it did not work, the batch file makes the exe run without uac, because i dont want to keep retyping the pass for it everytime i open it. problem is the exe file requires to be run from a launcher from developer. i cant find a way to make the exe file run through the batch when i try to open the exe file from the launcher

Comment: Some more information would be nice to help, what program is it?

Comment: program is called nexon game launcher. specific program im trying to run is vindictus.exe